# tabs.query case insensitive title

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to use `browser.tabs.query` in my WebExtension. It doesn't work in the case where the tab title does not match exactly.
What's more confusing is that docs say this about the parameter for `title`:

> string. Match page titles against a pattern.

So, I tried providing a RegEx string with case insensitive flag, but that doesn't seem to work either. Is there a way to get case insensitive matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebExtensions [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/07d7ecbf77e3be59797f16234d357a02bb38ed8b/browser/components/extensions/ext-tabs.js#683) indicates that only an exact match is tested for the `title` property. This is different than Chrome, which [does use a match pattern](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_api.cc?rcl=0&l=965) for `title`.

If you want a case insensitive match, or to use a RegEx, you will have to perform the `tabs.query()` without the `title` property and then filter the resulting tabs yourself based on the `tab.title` property.

Comment: Yeah, I started to just change [`tabs.query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query). Prior to doing so, I checked the Chrome source code. After discovering that the issue is really a Firefox incompatibility, it will need to be added to list of Firefox incompatibilities for `tabs.query`. Making such changes is a somewhat longer process: fork the project on GitHub, make changes, then submit a pull request, then wait for the pull request to be integrated, or questioned. Probably should submit a bugzilla bug too.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334782